# Winsock: Структура in_addr структуры sockaddr_in

Tags: c++, c, winapi, winsock

Вопрос больше из любопытства, может кто может объяснить в чем сакральный смысл структуры in_addr структуры sockaddr_in:
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsock2/ns-winsock2-in_addr

```
struct in_addr {
  union {
    struct {
      u_char s_b1;
      u_char s_b2;
      u_char s_b3;
      u_char s_b4;
    } S_un_b;
    struct {
      u_short s_w1;
      u_short s_w2;
    } S_un_w;
    u_long S_addr;
  } S_un;
};
```

То есть эста структура предназначена для хранения IPv4 адреса, я просто не понимаю зачем аж целых три варианта хранения:

-В виде массива 4 char`ов

-В виде массиве 2ух unsigned short`ов

-И в виде одного unsigned long

Просто, чем плох самый первый или любой из эти вариантов. Зачем сразу три ?

Comment: Для универсальности. Чтоб не надо было руками октеты выдирать...

Comment: Этой библиотеке кажется более 20-30 лет. Так уже случилось что библиотека именно такая. В то время видимо нужен был именно такой вид. Попытка изменть что-то потенциально может привести к тому что 99% программ перестанут работать (компилироваться). Эта библиотека используется очень часто.

Comment: Кроме ipv4 не считая ipv6 есть ещё и другие способы коннекта. Надо хорошо знать все разновидности сетей что бы ответить на этот вопрос. Бывают и не ip сети. Может быть сейчас когда массово используется ipv4 кажется что дико что-то другое. Возможно лет через 10 будет считаться что дико то, что там нету ipv6, и её нужно брать с другой либы. А может китайцы свой формат введут, они там тоже что-то станное выдумывали.